# Calculating mean with probability density function - solved but unsure

Tags: probability

I have
and when $\alpha = 1 $, I have to find the mean of X, when X is a random variable with pdf
$$ f_X(x)  = \frac{\alpha}{(x+1)^{(\alpha+1)}},\ \ \ \ x \geq 0 $$
if $\alpha = 1$, $$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} $$
knowing that $$\mathbb E[x] =  \int_{0}^\infty xf_X(x) \ dx$$
I did
$$ \mathbb E[x] = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{x}{(x+1)^2} \ dx$$
Which the equation doesn't converge, there is no mean.

I was wondering if this is correct. Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and no write $\mathbb{E}[x]$. By other hand, yes it's correct your answer. For $\alpha=1$, the mean is undefined because $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_{X}(x)\, {\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x)^{2}}\, {\rm d}x$$doesn't converges by limit comparison test with $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$.